# Load data slow while fetching from firebase + iOS

Tags: ios, swift, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am preparing iOS native app with using firebase real database.

I have around 100k data.. I need to show recent 50 posts and after load more next 50 posts so I have implemented **paging** of 50 records still it took long time (approx 20-30 seconds).

ALSO I tried with **indexing** with rules in firebase.

FYI: It's working fine with 1000 records.

How can I improve the performance?

```
  let post_messagesReference = self.databaseRef.child(FirebaseTablePostMessages)
        var query = post_messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: kCreated)
        var lastKey = String()
        var createdVal = Int()
        if let last = self.endKeyCommunity.first {
            lastKey = last.id
            createdVal = Int(last.created)
        }

        //get first 50 records
        if self.endKeyCommunity.count == 0{
            query = query.queryLimited(toLast:50)
            self.showLoaderView()
        } else { //get next 50 records
            query = query.queryEnding(atValue: createdVal).queryLimited(toLast: 50)
        }
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    guard case let communityChatDictionary as NSDictionary = child.value else { return }
                    if lastKey != child.key{
                    }
                guard case let communityChatDictionary as NSDictionary = children.value else { return }

            }

        }) { (error) in
  }
```

[image: firebase rules index]

Comment: Please void using Indian words like 'lac'.

Comment: How long does the loading of the first 50 nodes take? How long does each subsequent 50 notes take? How big is each node? What is the bandwidth that you're testing on?

Comment: How big is each node? : 12 keys  What is the bandwidth that you're testing on?: 5 MBPS How long does the loading of the first 50 nodes take?: first 50 load 2-3 second but next 50 takes around 15-20 second.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your Firebase rules so you set:

```
".read": "query.orderByKey &&
            query.limitToFirst <= 100"
```

Remove this code `var query = post_messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: kCreated)`. Just call your paginated requests like that:

```
post_messagesReference.limitToFirst(50)
                  .orderByKey(kCreated)
```

Comment: now I can able to fetch first 50 records faster. how can I fetch next 50 records?

Comment: You can add at the end .startAt() and use the last created object from the first page you just fetched. Take a look at .startAt() and .endAt() from the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors